# How to view or redirect php.exe's stdout to a file?

Tags: php

I modified the php source file, add some printfs and now I'd like to see the result, but php is loaded as module of apache httpd. How could I view the result?

Thanks.

PS: I am working on Windows 7 + Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP usually writes to the Apache logs... did you check there?

If it isn't writing there, see what log mechanism PHP's source uses and copy that because PHP writes to apache logs :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP stdout come to browser.
stderr comes to error log.

Comment: According to my test, its stdout does not come to browser.

Comment: Just a question, did you run php as CGI or as apache module?If you're unsure plese check output of phpinfo